# Atom 'Select Next' selects more than just unique occurrences of a variable

Tags: atom-editor

```
is
this is really cool
code
this is really cool
code
```

Highlight the 'is' in the code above and press `alt-f3` on your keyboard. Only unique occurrences of 'is' should be highlighted. Atom currently highlights the 'is' in th'is' as well. I don't want this. How do I disable this behavior?

[image]

This is what I want to happen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was highlighting `is` and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>. This is not the correct way to `Select-Next`. You need to first put the cursor in front of the word you want to `Select-Next`, then press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>. I hope this helps somebody in the future.

*Bonus Tip - If you perform the same routine, but instead use <kbd>Alt-F3</kbd> you'll automatically select all occurrences of the word under consideration.*